# Does the c++ code in an Android Studio project ends up in the apk file (apart from the .so file)?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cmake, .so

When I include a c++ file in an Android Studio project, the code get compiled in to a .so file and gets included under 'lib' in the release apk file. Apart from that does the functions in c++ appear like the java methods appear in `classes.dex` file anywhere else in the apk ?

My objective is to make sure that every function in the c++ file only appears inside the .so file.

Comment: you mean methods like those: `Java_org_test_package_MainActivity_testMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance, ...)` ?

Comment: yes, I'm asking about the functions insides the c++ file which has the format you have mentioned.

Comment: ok, so what do you want to do with them?

Comment: I just want to make sure, local variables inside the c++ functions doesn't appear outside the .so file in the release-apk

Comment: yes, only those `Java_*` methods are visible, nothing more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, all your c++ classes compiled as .so files and your functions are hidden in it. These compiled files imported to your project by putting them in libs folder.

On the otherhand, you need to have JNI calls that bridge your c++ functions to be called by Java. These methods are written in Java side and compiled as dex (**d**alvik **ex**ecutable) files.

All these files are packaged as .APK file. It may look like a installation file but exactly its a compressed file. More likely .zip

Your questions answer; Your codes are only being in hidden .so and .dex files.

Answer (score 1):

It does not end up with apk file. it gives only .so and .a file . where .so file are shared library and .a files are static libraries which cant be used by android application.